# assign properties to wrong items in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**CODE**

> spider.py

```
...
def parse(self, response):
    for one_item in response.xpath('path1'):
        item = ProjectItem()
        request = scrapy.Request(one_item.xpath('path2'), callback=self.parse2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

property = []
def parse2(self, response)
   item = response.meta['item']

   for x in response.xpath('path3')
       self.property.append('path4')

   next_page = response.xpath('path5')
   if next_page is not None:
       request2 = scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse2)
       request2.meta['item'] = item
       yield request2
   else:
       item['field'] = self.property
       self.property = []
       yield item
```

Problem is that when spider crawl to `next_page`. Some `self.property` is assign to wrong items. I don't know how to repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.property` is a class attribute that is shared among all calls to `parse2` and you can't control the order of each call to `parse2` .

To solve that you need to pass the property list inside the meta or as a item attribute:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for one_item in response.xpath('path1'):
        item = ProjectItem()
        item['field'] = []
        request = scrapy.Request(one_item.xpath('path2'), callback=self.parse2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse2(self, response)
   item = response.meta['item']
   for x in response.xpath('path3')
       item['field'].append('path4')

   next_page = response.xpath('path5')
   if next_page is not None:
       request2 = scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse2)
       request2.meta['item'] = item
       yield request2
   else:
       yield item
```